How to define custom utility with media queries in Tailwind?
So, I have been trying to find a way to make my custom utilities, e.g., padding-root-inline responsive to screens sizes. So far, I know that I can do something like this-
@layer utilities {
    .padding-root-inline { ... }
    .padding-root-inline-sm { ... }
}

and then use screen modifiers like this-
<section class="padding-root-inline max-sm:padding-root-inline-sm"></section>

But this still doesn't seem convenient as I have to write the varient class along with the base class in each of the components I use it in. What I want is something like this-
@layer utilities {
    @media all and (max-width: theme('screens.xs')) {
        .padding-root-inline {
            padding-inline: calc(theme('padding.root-inline') - 2rem);
        }
    }
}

so that I could just say padding-root-inline and it would be responsive on its own, without the need to say sm:padding-root-inline-sm.

You can directly define the media queries within your custom utility:
@layer utilities {
    .padding-root-inline {
        padding-inline: calc(theme('padding.root-inline') - 2rem);

        @media (min-width: theme('screens.sm')) {
            padding-inline: ...
        }

        @media (min-width: theme('screens.md')) {
            padding-inline: ...
        }

        //...and so on
    }
}


I tried it but it doesn't work!

I don't see any problem with this approach, check playground. The class is added to the text that states "HERE IS AN EXAMPLE..."

I see though, it's not working on my end for whatever reason. But I'll figure it out. Thanks for the reference :)
